# PHP SimpleXML Get One Node with Children via Attribute

Tags: php, xml

Have not found a direct solution and would prefer to do this with SimpleXML ... want to get a single node and children via an attribute (id) from a sent url

Address is clicked ...

www.website.com/index.php#929495820

XML

```
<archive>
  <unit id="925535820">
    <data>Blah</data>
    <link>url</link>
  </unit>
  <unit id="929495820">
    <data>Blah</data>
    <link>url</link>
  </unit>
  <unit id="929495821">
    <data>Blah</data>
    <link>url</link>
  </unit> ... and many more ...
</archive>
```

I have php that turns the entire XML in to an array and then splice to limit what is shown (see below) but what I want is the url to grab the single value from the array. Can it be done and if so, Simple or Dom? Please say Simple. I have the worst luck working Dom.

```
$xml_get = 'filename.xml'
$xml_array = json_decode(json_encode($xml_get), 1);
$master = $xml_array['unit'];
// Show Last 200
$master = array_slice($master, 1, 200);
foreach(array_reverse($master) as $arc)
{
$last_id = $arc['@attributes']['id'];
$last_data = $arc['data'];
$last_link = $arc['link'];
// Do stuff with values...
}
```

Comment: Silly question: does `json_decode()` parse XML?

Comment: @paulsm4 It seems to. You are not the first person to poo-poo that ... starting to believe I shd approach this differently.

Comment: Smart kids use xPath for things like this.

Comment: @Viney Which is almost certainly why I have not used it yet :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use SimpleXML you could load the file with [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) and check the [`attributes`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) for your id.

Then use for example a `foreach` or an xpath expression:

```
$elm = simplexml_load_file("filename.xml");

foreach ($elm->unit as $item) {
    if ((string)$item->attributes()->id === "929495820") {
        echo $item->data;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $item->link;
    }
}

$result = $elm->xpath("/archive/unit[@id='929495820']");
echo $result[0]->data;
echo "<br>";
echo $result[0]->link;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tdDXb)

Comment: This ... this is outstandingly easy. Almost annoyingly easy. Thx! Now a question -> which method would you use in your application if you had to? Foreach or XPath?

Comment: Imho if you use the xpath suggestion you don't have to write the `foreach` and the `if` check. (Before using `$result[0]` check if that item exists in the array).